# Reset Input back to console window?

Tags: delphi, io, console, pascal

Is there any way in Free Pascal/Delphi to reset the standard `Input` file back to console window after it was assigned to a 'real file' temporarily?

```
     AssignFile(Input, 'stdin.txt');
     ...
     CloseFile(Input);
     // ??
     ReadLn(x); // I/O error
```

Comment: Have you tried Assignfile(Input, '') ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per Delphi's documentation:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AssignFile

> When the FileName parameter is empty, AssignFile associates F with the standard input or standard output file. If assigned an empty name, after a call to Reset (F), F refers to the standard input file, and after a call to Rewrite (F), F refers to the standard output file.